# How to run localhost on a port on a website with Flask

Tags: python, flask

so I'm trying to host my flask app on a site only when it's accessed via a certain port for example. If a user goes to www.example.com on port 80 the site acts normal and they connect to the site. However if they visit www.example.com on port 5000 they are greeted with my flask app, how can I achieve this? Side note as people are getting confused, I don't own www.example.com I just want it to display what's running on localhost (flask) when it's accessed on a certain port.

Comment: add code snippet please !!!

Comment: The default flask port is 5000. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @utks009 I'm asking for a code snippet I don't currently have one

Comment: @roganjosh Basically if I put in my hostfiles 127.0.0.1 www.example.com everytime I connect to example.com it goes to localhost I only want it to go to localhost if I'm connecting on a certain port.

Answer (score 0):

You can run both the applications at the same time. Since Flask and the webserver run on different ports, they can co-exist without any issue.

However, you need to make sure clients have access to both port 80 (usually this is allowed from most firewalls and access restricting methods) and 5000 from client devices.

Comment: How can I configure example.com to only display localhost when it's on a certain port in my hostfiles though? I tried adding 127.0.0.1 www.example.com:5000 to my hostiles and it wouldn't connect to localhost, just to be clear I don't own the site.